# Mustache: get value by key

Tags: mustache, canjs, canjs-view

How to use mustache for the following scenario:

```
el.html( can.view('ideasView', {ideas: records, photos: jQuery.parseJSON(users)}));
```

Is it possible to access photo by {{photos[id].photoUrl}}?
I need to get photoUrl by ideas[i].Id when looping through ideas.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You'll need to prepare your data in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this without knowing how your photos data is structured. But from how I'm interpreting your data structure from you question. You could try

{{#ideas}} {{id}} {{\ideas}}